# Convert an ArrayList produced by file whose elements seperated to Integer Array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, list, file, arraylist

I am very new to File operations in Java. I have a file consisting of numbers like below.

6

1 2

1 3

I am trying to put all these numbers in file into an integer array. I found a prepared code to put them in a String list but it is not useless for me now. What I want to do is to store them in a int array and reach them index by index. I want to have int[]NumbersFromFile ={6,1,2,1,3};
Here is my code

```
 public String[] ReadNumbersFromFile(String name) throws FileNotFoundException {
    String token1 = "";

    Scanner inFile1 = new Scanner(new File(name)).useDelimiter(",\\s*");

    ArrayList<String> temps = new ArrayList<String>();

    // while loop
    while (inFile1.hasNext()) {
       // find next line
       token1 = inFile1.next();
       temps.add(token1);
    }
    inFile1.close();
    String[] tempsArray = new String[temps.size()];
    tempsArray = temps.toArray(tempsArray);

    for (String s  : tempsArray)
    {
       System.out.print(s);
    }

    return tempsArray;
 }
```

How can I obtain the int array from this file?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop through the arrayList and add to and int[] instead of string[] like this:

```
public int[] ReadNumbersFromFile(String name) throws FileNotFoundException {
    //String to store each number from the file
    String token1 = "";

    //Open the file and create a scanner to read it
    Scanner inFile1 = new Scanner(new File(name));

    //temporary arrayList to store what we read from the file
    //scanners return strings
    ArrayList<String> temps = new ArrayList<String>();

    // while the scanner can see it has more to read
    while (inFile1.hasNext()) {
        // save the number read
        token1 = inFile1.next();

        //add it to the arrayList
        temps.add(token1);
    }

    //close the scanner when done using to free up that resource
    inFile1.close();

    //create the standard int array that is the same length as the arrayList<String>
    int[] tempsArray = new int[temps.size()];

    //loop through the arrayList<String>
    //this is what contains each number from the file, just as Strings
    for(int i = 0; i < temps.size(); i++) {
        //Integar.parseInt(String s) takes a string of numbers and returns it as int
        //save this to our int[]
        tempsArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(temps.get(i));
    }

    //return the int[]
    return tempsArray;
}
```

Comment: @frenchDolphin It stores all the numbers at the tempsArray[0]  that the reason why parse is not working i tried it. How can i handle this case ?

Comment: @B.U frenchDolphin's is the other answer. Try my code and see if it works.  I made an edit to it because you shouldn't need to change the delimiter.

Comment: Thank you so much it works now. Could you explain the logic behind it?  @MrMadsen

Comment: @B.U Yeah, I edited the post with a comment before each line explaining what it is doing.  If you still have a question about a specific line let me know and I'll answer it here.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
ArrayList<String> temps = new ArrayList<String>();
```

to this:

```
ArrayList<Integer> temps = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

And change this line:

```
token1 = inFile1.next();
```

to this:

```
token1 = inFile1.nextInt();
```

Alternatively, you could write a for loop to parse the ArrayList to an int[] using `Integer.parseInt(yourInt)`.

```
int[] ints = new int[temps.size()];
for(int i = 0; i < temsp.size(); i++) {
    ints[i] = Integer.parseInt(temps.get(i));
}
```